# Facebook GraphRequest returning illegitimate results on different profiles

Tags: java, android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an application which has a login/register with Facebook option. The functionality is working fine for some profiles and causing issues on other profiles. I wanted to get the following data from the user's profile:

**id,name,email,gender,birthday,location**

The function dealing with Facebook login:

```
private void fromFaceBookLogin() {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                      Log.e("onCompleted", ""+ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());

                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                      JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();

                      try {
                          Log.e("jsonObject", jsonObject.toString());
                        userProfile.put("facebookId", jsonObject.getLong("id"));
                        userId = jsonObject.getLong("id");
                        userProfile.put("name", jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        //splitting first and last names
                        String[] parts = jsonObject.getString("name").split(" ");
                        firstName = parts[0]; // 004
                        lastName = parts[1]; // 034556

                        if (jsonObject.getString("gender") != null) {
                            userProfile.put("gender", jsonObject.getString("gender"));

                        }
                          Log.e("gender", jsonObject.getString("gender"));
                        if (jsonObject.getString("email") != null) {
                            userProfile.put("email", jsonObject.getString("email"));
                        }
                        email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                        Log.e("email", jsonObject.getString("email"));
                        birthDay = jsonObject.getString("birthday");
                        dateOfBirth = alterFaceBookDateObject(birthDay);
                        //countryFrom = pushBackCountry((String) jsonObject.getString("location").);
                        JSONObject weatherObservationItems = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("location"));
                           countryFrom = pushBackCountry( weatherObservationItems.getString("name"));
                        authData = userProfile;
                        try {
                            new obtainFaceBookProfilePhotoTask(LoadingFacebookDetails.this).execute().get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                       // goToPhotoBeforeSave(true);
                      } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error parsing returned user data", "" + e);
                      }
                    } else if (graphResponse.getError() != null) {
                      switch (graphResponse.getError().getCategory()) {
                        case LOGIN_RECOVERABLE:
                          Log.e("Authentication error",
                                  "Authentication error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                          break;

                        case TRANSIENT:
                          Log.e("Transient error. Try again",
                                  "Transient error. Try again. " + graphResponse.getError());
                          break;

                        case OTHER:
                          Log.e("Some other error",
                                  "Some other error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                          break;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,location");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();


    }
```

**The legitimate JSON output obtained using the above function:**

```
{"id":"887845xxxxxxx0","name":"John Lenon","email":"john@yahoo.co.in","gender":"male","birthday":"06\/20\/1988","location":{"id":"106517799384578","name":"New Delhi, India"}}
```

**The illegitimate JSON output obtained using the above function:**

```
{"id":"2709969xxxx35","gender":"male","email":"help@gmail.com","name":"Rohan Lalwani"}
```

The error shown in logcat:

```
01-12 15:13:08.699 30427-30427/? E/Error parsing returned user data: org.json.JSONException: No value for birthday
```

The second profile shows all values when checked in Facebook page.

**The gradle dependency section:**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Viewpage:viewpage-library')
    compile project(':CountryPicker')
    compile project(':numberpicker-library')
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'



    //compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.+'


    //compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
   // compile fileTree(include: ['ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.2.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: ['jsoup-1.7.3.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile fileTree(include: ['ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.3.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    // compile fileTree(include: ['libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['android-support-multidex.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'



   // compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

}
```

**The library structure of the project:**

[image]

Where am I going wrong? Why the profiles are behaving differently? What should be done to handle the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly issue with *facebook graph api* as to fetch **birthday,location**  permission's developer have to submit application for **Review** , Now for testing purpose facebook api only return these details only to the **Administrators , Developers or Testers** as maintained on **Roles** tab of [facebook developer portal](https://developers.facebook.com/).

so In your case too it is the case where you can get birthday from api response as  are trying to fetch those details from email id maintained on **Roles** tab and same response will not be delivered from graph api for other emailId's so on successful testing to get birthday in response from graph api for all users you have to Submit app for Review [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit)  .

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the user has their birthday listed on their public profile, ive encountered this error a few times when parsing images in an album,
when using

```
response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
```

on JSONArrays if the image does not have a description I would get the error:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for name
```